# Mockery mocking os.type() is not working

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocking, mocha.js, mockery

I'm trying to unit test a module of mine which is dependent on the underlying OS.

I'm trying to use mockery to mock os.type() to return Linux/Windows_NT based on the different tests fixtures.

I'm using mocha as my unit test framework.

I have a describe section that unit tests functionality A of my module which has 2 describe blocks inside of it: one for Windows and one for Linux.

Setup:
    var reload = require("require-reload")(require);
    var module_we_test = reload('...');

```
var linuxOsMock = {
    type: function () {
        return "Linux";
    }
};

var windowsOsMock = {
    type: function () {
        return "Windows_NT";
    }
};


describe('#the_module_we_test', function() {
    before(function() {
        mockery.enable({
            warnOnReplace: false
        });
    });
    after(function() {
        mockery.disable();
    });
    describe('#windows', function() {
        before(function() {
            mockery.registerMock('os', windowsOsMock);
            module_we_test = reload('...');
        });
        describe('#functionality A', function() {
            it('...', function() {
                /* tests functionality A which is OS dependnet */
                module_we_test.functionalityA();
            });
        });
    describe('#linux & darwin', function() {
        before(function() {
            mockery.registerMock('os', linuxOsMock);
            module_we_test = reload('...');
        });
        describe('#functionality A', function() {
            it('...', function() {
                /* tests functionality A which is OS dependnet */
                module_we_test.functionalityA();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The reason I require the module I'm testing before each OS dependent test fixture is because the module is using the OS module once in the global scope to decide some variable values like so:

```
var os = require('os');
var osType = os.type();

/* decide variable values based on os.type() return value */
```

so, *I think* unless I require it again, before each fixture it'll have the originally loaded OS module loaded instead of my mock.

Now, the problem is that it just doesn't replace the OS module in the module, and I have no clue why.

Comment: Do you load the `os` module in other modules apart from the module under test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because on top you do `var module_we_test = require('...');`. This will load the original module and keep it in cache. So even if you mock it using mockery everytime you require it you will get back the cached original module. You need to use mockery first to mock the module and then `reload` the module under test. The reloaded module will retrieve the mocked module now. You can do this by using the [require-reload][1] module.

**Working example**

```
describe('#the_module_we_test', function() {
    before(function() {
        mockery.enable({
            warnOnReplace: false
        });
    });
    after(function() {
        mockery.disable();
    });
    describe('#windows', function() {
        var module_we_test;
        before(function() {
            mockery.registerMock("os", windowsOsMock);
            module_we_test = reload("...");
        });
        after(function(){
            mockery.deregisterMock(windowsOsMock);
        });

        it("#functionality A", function() {
            /* tests functionality A which is OS dependnet */
            assert.equal(module_we_test.type(), "Windows_NT");
        });
    });
    describe('#linux', function() {
        var module_we_test;
        before(function() {
            mockery.registerMock("os", linuxOsMock);
            module_we_test = reload("...");
        });
        after(function(){
            mockery.deregisterMock(linuxOsMock);
        });

        it("#functionality A", function() {
            /* tests functionality A which is OS dependnet */
            assert.equal(module_we_test.type(), "Linux");
        });
    });
});
```

**Update**

After reading more thoroughly the documentation of `mockery`, it seems that it provides clean-cache functionality. So instead of using `require-reload` you only have to set

```
before(function() {
    mockery.enable({
        warnOnReplace: false,
        useCleanCache: true
    });
});
```

and `require` normally the module that loads your mocked-module. In the `after` hook of your `os` describe you need to call `mockery.resetCache`

```
after(function(){
    mockery.deregisterMock(windowsOsMock);
    mockery.resetCache();
});
```

I believe this is the best way to tackle this scenario using the `mockery` module

Comment: I've used reload as u suggested and I reload it before each test fixture which is related to specific Os, yet when I debug the Linux fixture I still get Windows_NT as my osType, ill update the op

Comment: @Jorayen Don't forget to deregister your mock in the describe block.

Comment: still not working, I don't know what I am doing wrong firt time using mockery, it'll be helpful if you could write me a working template

Comment: @Jorayen I added a working example which I run on my machine. Hope that helps. Also, no nee to  reload the `module_we_test` on top of your file.  Just see what I did in my example

Comment: Superb! Seems like requiring the module_we_test in the top of the file caused the problem instead of just using it in the fixture scope.